# Format array items for string output

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

I'm trying to display the items in an array using the following:

```
NSString *alertString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", path];
```

Which works fine, but when I display the string it gets displayed in the following way:

(
A,
B,
C,
D
)

Is there a way to get it to display in a different way, such as all on one line and without brackets, commas or line returns like this:

A B C D

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have a few options. It looks like the objects within the array have a `description` method that prints them the way you want to, so it may be as simple as using:

```
NSString *alertString = [path componentsJoinedByString:@" "];
```

If not, you could consider something like this:

```
NSMutableString *s = [NSMutableString string];
[path enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    [s appendString:@" "];
    [s appendString:[obj someMethodThatFormatsTheObject]];
}];
NSString *alertString = [NSString stringWithString:s];
```

Or even:

```
NSMutableArray *a = [NSMutableArray array];
[path enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    [a addObject:[obj sometMethodThatFormatsTheObject]];
}];
NSString *alertString = [a componentsJoinedByString:@" "];
```

Comment: Picked this one purely because it was detailed. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 9):

If that `path` is an NSArray, you could use [the `-componentsJoinedByString:` method](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/componentsJoinedByString:) to concatenate all strings in the array with the desired separator.

```
NSString* alertString = [path componentsJoinedByString:@" "];
```